# Tissues in plants and animals

Tags: tissue

- What is the equivalent connective tissue in plants?

Connective tissue in animals are mostly made up of collagen.

- What about in plants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Connective tissue in animals are mostly made up of collagen

- Tissue is not like a simple chemical mixture ; rather [tissue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissue_(biology)) means a group or assemblage of cells, obeying certain defining-characteristics.
- Animal connective tissues contain [collagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collagen) mostly in the [extracellular matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extracellular_matrix). There are also other cell-constituents like phospholipid(membranes), DNA, RNA, etc.  Blood is a liquid connective tissue which do not contain collagen in its matrix (plasma)

> What is the equivalent connective tissue in plants?

- [Connective tissue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connective_tissue) is defined as all the tissues originated from the [mesoderm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesoderm) layer of the animal embryo.

Now plants have a different mode of development than animals (plausibly due to evolution in separate route). So **no** part of a plant-body is [homologous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(biology)) with a part of animal-body. It is impossible to bring a compare.

---

However; plants too; have their extracellular matrix; which is more popular as plant's cell wall (that contain cellulose, hemicellulose, etc.) as well there are intercellular spaces.

---

Still, if you forcefully want to bring a comparison; then the [ground-tissue system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_tissue) of plant maybe called as a rough [analogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Analogy_(biology)&redirect=no) with connective tissues in animals ( Similarly epidermal tissue of plant maybe a rough analogy with epithelial tissue of animals)